# How do I discard Image Position after Animation on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am doing a scale and translate animation using the code below. This moves an image from bottom left to center of screen. Next time when I do animation I want to restart from bottom left. But the animation doesn't start. What do I need to restart the animation ?

```
// Setup the animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

// The transform matrix
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);    
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0,2.0);
CGAffineTransform scale_transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform,scale);

image.transform = scale_transform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out. This is what solved it.

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```